# Linter complaining when instance variable of subclass is another subclass instance, which can have different instance variables

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, pylance

This is a bit confusing, and I tried to explain it in simple English but it's hard to follow. Instead, I have written the following toy code to illustrate the problem. This code runs fine and prints the expected output, however my linter complains on the lines shown.

1. Is this an issue with the linter?
2. Or can I do something to stop the linter complaining about this?
3. Or is this bad practice/design and I should fix it somehow?

```
from abc import ABC


class SuperClassVariable(ABC):
    def __init__(self, shared_value: str):
        self.shared_value = shared_value


class SubClassVariable1(SuperClassVariable):
    def __init__(self, shared_value: str, sub_class_value_1: str):
        super().__init__(shared_value=shared_value)
        self.sub_class_value_1 = sub_class_value_1


class SubClassVariable2(SuperClassVariable):
    def __init__(self, shared_value: str, sub_class_value_2: str):
        super().__init__(shared_value=shared_value)
        self.sub_class_value_2 = sub_class_value_2


class SuperClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self, sub_class_variable: SuperClassVariable):
        self.sub_class_variable = sub_class_variable


class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, sub_class_variable: SubClassVariable1):
        super().__init__(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable)


class SubClass2(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, sub_class_variable: SubClassVariable2):
        super().__init__(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable)


sub_class_variable_1 = SubClassVariable1(
    shared_value="shared_value", 
    sub_class_value_1="sub_class_variable_1"
)
sub_class_variable_2 = SubClassVariable2(
    shared_value="shared_value", 
    sub_class_value_2="sub_class_variable_2"
)

sub_class_1 = SubClass1(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable_1)
sub_class_2 = SubClass2(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable_2)

print(sub_class_1.sub_class_variable.shared_value)      # OK
print(sub_class_1.sub_class_variable.sub_class_value_1) # Cannot access member "sub_class_value_1" for type "SuperClassVariable"
print(sub_class_2.sub_class_variable.shared_value)      # OK
print(sub_class_2.sub_class_variable.sub_class_value_2) # Cannot access member "sub_class_value_1" for type "SuperClassVariable"
```

Output:

```
shared_value
sub_class_variable_1
shared_value
sub_class_variable_2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it as shown. Not sure if this is the best/correct way for this. I believe using typing. Generic may be a more accepted way to fix this issue, but I prefer to show the superclass name as the type hint rather than a generic type.

```
from abc import ABC


class SuperClassVariable(ABC):
    def __init__(self, shared_value: str):
        self.shared_value = shared_value


class SubClassVariable1(SuperClassVariable):
    def __init__(self, shared_value: str, sub_class_value_1: str):
        super().__init__(shared_value=shared_value)
        self.sub_class_value_1 = sub_class_value_1


class SubClassVariable2(SuperClassVariable):
    def __init__(self, shared_value: str, sub_class_value_2: str):
        super().__init__(shared_value=shared_value)
        self.sub_class_value_2 = sub_class_value_2


class SuperClass(ABC):
    def __init__(self, sub_class_variable: SuperClassVariable):
        self.sub_class_variable = sub_class_variable


class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    sub_class_variable: SubClassVariable1

    def __init__(self, sub_class_variable: SubClassVariable1):
        super().__init__(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable)


class SubClass2(SuperClass):
    sub_class_variable: SubClassVariable2

    def __init__(self, sub_class_variable: SubClassVariable2):
        super().__init__(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable)


sub_class_variable_1 = SubClassVariable1(
    shared_value="shared_value", 
    sub_class_value_1="sub_class_variable_1"
)
sub_class_variable_2 = SubClassVariable2(
    shared_value="shared_value", 
    sub_class_value_2="sub_class_variable_2"
)

sub_class_1 = SubClass1(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable_1)
sub_class_2 = SubClass2(sub_class_variable=sub_class_variable_2)

print(sub_class_1.sub_class_variable.shared_value)      # OK
print(sub_class_1.sub_class_variable.sub_class_value_1) # OK
print(sub_class_2.sub_class_variable.shared_value)      # OK
print(sub_class_2.sub_class_variable.sub_class_value_2) # OK
```